# Stein fillable tight contact structures on the 3-torus

Tags: 3-manifolds, contact-geometry, stein-manifolds, torus

Kanda classified tight contact structures on the 3-torus. Which of them is Stein fillable? Is there any good reference?

Answer (score 4):

Eliashberg proved only one of them is Stein fillable (and in fact it's the only one that's strongly fillable). The paper is quite short.

Y. Eliashberg, *[Unique holomorphically fillable contact structure on the 3-torus](https://doi.org/10.1155/S1073792896000074)*,
Internat. Math. Res. Notices (1996), no. 2, 77–82.

I also highly recommend Chris Wendl's 2014 series of blog posts surveying symplectic fillings. The [fifth entry in the series](https://symplecticfieldtheorist.wordpress.com/2014/12/23/a-biased-survey-on-symplectic-fillings-part-5-tight-vs-weak-vs-strong/) specifically addresses the question you ask (assuming you know that all of the tight contact structures on $T^3$ are those given by $(T^3,\xi_k)$). I would be remiss if I didn't also mention Wendl's paper, which further proves that there is a unique minimal strong filling (up to the proper notion of equivalence), which is the Stein filling $D^*T^2 = T^2 \times D^2$ you know and love.

Wendl, Chris, *[Strongly fillable contact manifolds and $J$-holomorphic foliations](https://doi.org/10.1215/00127094-2010-001)*. Duke Math. J. 151 (2010), no. 3, 337–384.

Comment: These are all stated up to contactomorphism. Up to contact isotopy, there are infinitely distinct many tight contact structures that are all contactomorphic to the standard Stein fillable one.

Comment: Because contact isotopy generates contactomorphisms, we have that up to contact isotopy, tight contact structures up to isotopy are in bijection with $MCG(T^3)/\mathrm{Stab}(\xi_0)$. On the one hand, $MCG(T^3) = GL_3(\mathbb{Z})$. On the other hand, given $\xi_0$, $T^3$ comes with a canonical generator $\gamma \in H_1(T^3)$ coming from representing the unique class nulhomologous with respect to the Stein filling, and $\mathrm{Stab}(\xi_0)$ consists precisely of those elements fixing this class, i.e. $\mathrm{Stab}(\xi_0) = \mathbb{Z}^2 \rtimes \mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: To clarify, the quotient is therefore just in bijection with primitive elements in $\mathbb{Z}^3$ (given by the image of $\gamma$).